# What are these red squares in Visual Studio while using Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]There are some weird red squares in my Visual Studio Code. Any ideas where do they come from?

Clicks or hovering doesn't show anything. They aren't breakpoints also (breakpoints are red dots, and program doesn't break on these squares)

Edit: updated photo, added some new information.

Comment: Breakpoints maybe?

Comment: What does hovering the mouse above one, or clicking it do?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on that? When there are code changes it will show these kind of squares. Please try clicking on that and see if it shows the changes

Comment: Clicks or hovering doesn't show anything. They aren't breakpoints also (breakpoints are red dots, and program doesn't break on these squares)

Answer (score 0):

In general they could be potential errors in the code or linting errors. For example, line 34 calls `hex_to_binary(string)` when it looks to me that it should read `hex_to_binary(hex_string)`.

Comment: Good catch, but I had ```string``` variable already on top, so program would work anyway. They aren't linting errors, I changed it to ```hex_string```, but it still didn't remove them. Already edited the photo in original question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the extension you had installed caused it, you can try to disable all the extensions. Or maybe the caches caused it. So, try to copy the code, delete the file, recreate the file and past the code.